# How to skip 'null' elements when mapping array in react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, wordpress-rest-api, headless-cms

It seems like I'm getting the posts array fine like below

```
posts: [ ]
0: { }
1: { }
2: null
3: null
4: { }
```

Not sure why some of them are null? Im using nextjs and headless wordpress.
Anyone know of a solution to skip over the nulls? or maybe Im not calling the right posts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you tried so far, can you post the code?

Comment: I tried this but it breaks

`{posts.map((post, key) => (<div key={key}>{post.title}</div>))}`

Comment: as I wrote in another comment, you can try this: `{posts.map((post, key) => ( post && <div key={key}> {post.title} </div> ))}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do it with map,

it will be better if you just filter it out before mapping

```js
posts
.filter(x => x !== null) // this step will remove nulls
.map(x => {/* your logic */})
```

Comment: technically you can, you can have `{posts.map((post, key) => ( post && <div key={key}> {post.title} </div> ))}`

Comment: It is a solution but you still map over the null values, you just don't render them.